# lwip DHCP client not visible in Router's Active IP Table

Tags: networking, embedded, lwip

I've developed an lwip client on a microcontroller that *does* seem to successfully acquire an IP address whenever it is powered up.  Also, the device is successfully responding to network-based queries (e.g. socket-based commands, web page "GETs").

The problem I'm having is when I look at the router's "Active IP Table" the device is not present and I'm beginning to wonder if I've done something wrong in the lwip startup procedures.

Does anyone know where I should begin to troubleshoot this?

**UPDATE (10/20/2011):**

I'm becoming convinced that the device's MAC address is at least somewhat responsible.  I discovered conflicting MAC addresses for the target when comparing my Windows ARP table and the MAC address I *believed* I was setting in the lwip initializations.

Comment: I'm assuming the router is the DHCP server (or maybe you are using link-local addressing?) When you connect another, 'known good' device to the router, does it get an IP address, and is this shown in the Active IP table? Router software has been known to contain bugs!

Comment: @Max - Yes, the router is a DHCP server and other 'known good' devices do show up in the Active IP Table.

Comment: When you say "does *seem* to successfully acquire an IP address" are you saying via DHCP?  Are you *sure* it's using DHCP on the MCU side?  Maybe the MCU's IP address just hard-coded.  Since the MCU is responding to network queries, it's clear it's on the network & that the stack is working... it just might not be using a dynamic IP address.  The router probably only displays dynamic IPs that are acquired via DHCP.

Comment: @Dan - Good question. I believe the MCU is acquiring IP addresses via DHCP. Over time, the MCU acquires and responds to different IP addresses (e.g. today: 192.168.1.102,  yesterday: 192.168.1.105) all with the same load of software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to my problem was associated with multiple MAC addresses (5 unique addresses) being used throughout the codebase.